# How to print accuracy of different activation layers while training a Keras functional API model? (Tensorflow Python)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, functional-api

I have used the Functional API to create a model with three different output layers to test different activation functions. The problem is that the output line for each epoch is too long. I only want to look at the accuracy and not the loss.

```py
Epoch 1/5
1875/1875 - 4s - loss: 3.7070 - Sigmoid_loss: 1.1836 - Softmax_loss: 1.2291 - Softplus_loss: 1.2943 - Sigmoid_accuracy: 0.9021 - Softmax_accuracy: 0.9020 - Softplus_accuracy: 0.5787
```

I don't want the `.fit()` function to print the loss for each layer, only the accuracy. I searched all of Google and Tensorflow Documentation but couldn't find how to do it.

If you want the complete code, comment on this post. I will send it immediately.

Here is the model's summary:

```py
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
InputLayer (InputLayer)         [(32, 784)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
FirstHidden (Dense)             (32, 512)            401920      InputLayer[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
SecondHidden (Dense)            (32, 256)            131328      FirstHidden[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Sigmoid (Dense)                 (32, 10)             2570        SecondHidden[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Softmax (Dense)                 (32, 10)             2570        SecondHidden[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Softplus (Dense)                (32, 10)             2570        SecondHidden[0][0]               
==================================================================================================
Total params: 540,958
Trainable params: 540,958
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

***Thank You and have a nice day ahead.***

Comment: The only way I can think of is to set verbose=0 in model.fit. That I believe stops all printing during training. Then you have to create a custom callback that will print the metric data you wish. Documentation on how to create a custom callback is at https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/. Define the function on_epoch_end to print you metric data.

Comment: @GerryP you are right, verbose=0 will stop printing everything during training but what I want is that the model.fit function should print just the accuracy of each layer and not the loss.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my shot at the custom callback. Note I assume that Sigmoid_accuracy, Softmax_accuracy and Softplus_accuracy are defined previously as metrics in model.compile.
Here is the code for the custom callback

```
class Print_Acc(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Print_Acc, self).__init__() 
        
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):  # method runs on the end of each epoch
        sig_acc=logs.get('Sigmoid_accuracy')  
        softmax_acc =logs.get('Softmax_accuracy')
        softplus_acc =logs.get('Softplus_accuracy')
        print('For epoch ',epoch, ' sig acc= ', sig_acc, ' softmac acc= ', softmax_acc, ' softplus acc= ', softplus_acc)
```

in model.fit include callbacks=[Print_Acc]

Comment: did you try the callback? did it do what you wanted?

Comment: nah man, i had some school stuff... im gonna start again in a few days, hope to try this solution then ^_^